# How to add requirement of having a back facing camera in Manifest File?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I need to exclude devices which do not have a rear facing camera from installing the app. I am aware in AndoirdManifest.xml I can mention :-

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
  android:required="true" />
```

But this will still allow devices with no back facing camera(but they do have front facing camera) to install the app.

I read in android docs that we can mention subfeature requirement to have front facing camera

```
android:name="android.hardware.camera.front".
```

But is there a way I can mention the back facing camera as requirement. Something like

```
android:name="android.hardware.camera.back"
```

Also is there a way to test if this requirement will work before releasing it to play store. I tried to test this on emulators & devices but the application always gets installed from the eclipse even when they don't have any camera at all.

Thanks !!
Gagan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But this will still allow devices with no back facing camera(but they do have front facing camera) to install the app

Not according to [Google](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/07/getting-your-app-ready-for-jelly-bean.html):

> A single front facing camera (apps requiring the android.hardware.camera feature will not be available on Nexus 7)

Hence, the right answer would appear to be your first code snippet above.

If you have evidence that your snippet will not block the 1st generation Nexus 7, please post it.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I think it should resolve my issue. Will keep posted if this doesn't work.

Comment: This does not work. Using the android.hardware.camera value, 2012 Nexus 7 is not excluded automatically by Google Play Store.